# The H2 database is not created

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, h2

I am doing simple project in Spring. For now, I'm rewriting the code from the tutorial, but the H2 table is not created. The only difference in my code is that @Entity is marked as deprecated, and in the tutorial is not. Could anybody help me? Thank you in avance.

This is my code from .pom file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>project</groupId>
    <artifactId>cookbook</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>cookbook</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

aplication.properties file:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

and one of my model class:

```
    @Entity
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
...
```

[print screen of h2 database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyyE4.png)

Comment: How do you know its not created ? And please Also post your complete pom.xml

Comment: @georgesvan I've just edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the @Entity annotation is marked as deprecated that probably means you're importing Hibernate's annotation rather than the JavaEE `javax.persistence.Entity`. You can find some examples of this in Hibernate's own [test suite](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/e5dc635a52362f69b69acb8d5b166b69b165dbbd/hibernate-core/src/test/java/org/hibernate/test/annotations/cascade/multicircle/jpa/identity/EntityB.java) or in just about any other [tutorial](https://www.journaldev.com/17803/jpa-hibernate-annotations). Even the official [Hibernate guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping) says to use `javax.persistence.*` annotations. Maybe this will solve your issue.

*Wanted to leave this as a comment but don't have the 50 rep required to do so.